# Resources for Relay Modern-React Native Integration

Tags: react-native, relayjs, relay

I'm just curious if there exist any good resources that show how to use relay modern with react native. I've found a few snippets here and there with react, but they aren't entirely congruent with react native set ups. Apollo has great docs, but seems to have a very different api.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

I've since found a GitHub repo which you may be interested in:

https://github.com/sibelius/ReactNavigationRelayModern

It's using: React Native + React-Navigation + Relay Modern

Answer (score -1):

You can find many useful repos like this one: https://github.com/sibelius/ReactNavigationRelayModern/

It got me started and I created my own repo. You can try this if you want to run local GraphQL server: https://github.com/jalalat/Realy-GraphQL-RN-MongoDB

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)